# Android Fragment tutorial force closes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I found [this](http://www.tellittotheblog.com/post/2011/03/25/Super-Simple-Fragments) tutorial for fragments, because I'm having a super hard time figuring them out. The application force closes and according to logcat "Error inflating class fragment".

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.learn.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /* Add a class to handle fragment */
    public static class SSFFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_frag, container, false);
            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <fragment class="SSFFragment"
   android:id="@+id/frag"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

hello_frag.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello_world"
/>
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm having a really though time looking for a simple fragment tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `activity_main.xml` you are naming fragment incorrectly.

Correct name should be `com.example.learn.fragments.MainActivity$SSFFragment`.

Comment: @EGHDK because you have to use fully qualified class name and your fragment is inner class, and $ symbol is used while giving fq name of inner classes in xml files.

Comment: Hmm... alright, this is gonna get tricky. Thanks though. I appreciate it.